# How to validate the Currency String in java

Tags: java, currency, currency-formatting

Suppose I have a currency String in German format:

```
String money="1.203.432,25";
```

I want to check if money is a valid currency value. 
"0,00" is valid, "134.20,24" is invalid, "02,23" is invalid and so on. How can I do it in Java?

Comment: Why is "02,23" invalid? That's about the cost in Euros of an espresso at a German railway station.

Comment: @Bathsheba it's most probably because of the leading zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet seems to work:

```
String money="23.234,00";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("^(?:0|[1-9]\\d{0,2}(?:\\.\\d{3})*),\\d{2}$");
Matcher m=p.matcher(money);
if (m.matches()) System.out.println("valid");
else System.out.println("invalid");
```

Comment: Side note: `Matcher.find()` would look for multiple occurences if you leave out `^` and `$`. Using `Matcher.matches()` would do the same and try to match the _entire_ input string.

Comment: Invalid for `0.1`

Comment: 0.1 is not a valid German currency value

Answer (score 2):

Use a localized number format (or a regex if it's always in German format).

Regex could be something like `^(?:0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:\.[0-9]{3})*),[0-9]{2}$`, with `^` and `$` not being necessary when using `String#matches()` or `Matcher#matches()`.

Number format could be a `DecimalFormat` like `###,##0.00` or just use `NumberFormat.getInstance( Locale.GERMAN )`. The problem with number formats, however, is that it allows a number to have leading zeros so if you want to disallow those you could check the first digit for being a zero or not.

Comment: NumberFormat didn't work, as it allowed e.g. leading zeros 

RegExp should it be, I think, just looking for the right now.

Comment: Looks like that ^(?:0|[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{3})*),\d{2}$ does the trick

Comment: @AlexeiVinogradov yes, that seems to be ok (I'll add that `0,xx` case to the answer for others to spot). Just note that `\d` would allow foreign digits as well so you might want to use `[0-9]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Apache [CurrencyValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/javadocs/api-1.4.1/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/CurrencyValidator.html) is what you are looking for.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
     BigDecimalValidator validator = CurrencyValidator.getInstance();

     BigDecimal amount = validator.validate("€ 123,00", Locale.GERMAN);

     if(amount == null){
         System.out.println("Invalid amount/currency.");
     }

}
```

Comment: Have you tested it with "023,00€"?

Comment: The leading zero is accepted, so it does not work for your case -sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Pattern: "([0-9]{1,3}\.)*[0-9]{1,3}\,[0-9]{2}"

```
System.out.println("11.118.576.587,58".matches("([0-9]{1,3}\\.)*[0-9]{1,3}\\,[0-9]{2}"));
```